# How to prove funciton continuity - hard one

Tags: derivatives, continuity

Let $f : (-5; 5) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be given as $f(x) = \sum_{n = 5}^{n = \infty}{\frac{1}{n^2-x^2}}$.How to prove that $f$ is continous? Is $f$ differentiable? If yes, how to compute $f'(0)$?  Edit: I tried to apply Weierstrass M-test.

Comment: Have you tried something Alex? (I don't want to assume you haven't).

Comment: The function certainly exists on the whole interval

Comment: As an aside, $\displaystyle\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty\frac1{x^2-n^2} ~=~ \frac\pi x~\cot\pi x$.

Comment: @SalmonKiller Why have you replaced $5$ with $\sqrt{5}$?

Comment: @alex Because it seemed like that would be the right interval. On this interval, the function is not continuous because at $x=\sqrt{5}$, it does not exist. Therefore, it is not continuous on that interval.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By a change of summation index $m=n-5$ , your sum becomes $\sum \limits _{m=0} ^\infty \frac 1 {(m+5)^2 - x^2} = \sum \limits _{m=0} ^\infty \frac 1 {m^2+ 10m + 5^2 - x^2} \leq \sum \limits _{m=0} ^\infty \frac 1 {m^2+ 10m}$ because $x \in (-5,5)$. The latter sum, in turn, is $\leq \sum \limits _{m=0} ^\infty \frac 1 {m^2}$ which is known to be convergent. Therefore, according to a theorem of Weierstrass, your series converges uniformly to $f$. Since each term of your series is continuous, then $f$ must be continuous (the uniform limit of a series of continuous functions is continuous).

Next, since the convergence is uniform and the terms of your series are derivable, so will be $f$. You compute $f'$ by deriving term-wise: $f' = \sum \limits _{n=5} ^\infty (\frac 1 {n^2 - x^2})' = \sum \limits _{n=5} ^\infty \frac {2x} {(n^2 - x^2)^2}$. It follows that $f'(0)=0$.